# C# Code to publish message to GCP topic without singleton instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

Thanks for all your support.
In my project I am trying to publish message to GCP pub/sub topic, manually. i.e. Developed an endpoint where will pass project id and topic name, based on this connection should create and message should publish to that topic.

I tried to publish message to GCP topic, by creating connection, but getting permission denied error.

Code:

public async Task PublisMessage(string documentId, ApiRequestHeaders MetaData, PubSubRequest pubSubModel)
{
bool isPublisehd = false;
string jsonPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS");

```
////// [START create_publisher_client]
//GoogleCredential googleCredential = null;
//using (var jsonStream = new FileStream(jsonPath, FileMode.Open,
//    FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
//{
//    googleCredential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(jsonStream);
//}
//////Channel channel = new Channel(PublisherClient.DefaultEndpoint.Host,
//////    PublisherClient.DefaultEndpoint.Port,
//////    googleCredential.ToChannelCredentials());

//var createSettings = new PublisherClient.ClientCreationSettings(credentials: googleCredential.ToChannelCredentials());

var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(jsonPath);
var createSettings = new PublisherClient.ClientCreationSettings(
    credentials: credential.ToChannelCredentials());


// [START create_topic]
TopicName topicName = new TopicName(pubSubModel.ProjectId, pubSubModel.TopicName);

try
{
    //PublisherClient _publisher = PublisherClient.Create(topicName, createSettings);
    PublisherClient _publisher = await PublisherClient.CreateAsync(topicName,
    clientCreationSettings: createSettings);

    var _message = await GetPublisMessage(documentId, MetaData);

    var acknowledgmentNumber = await _publisher.PublishAsync(_message);
    _logger.Info($"Message published to pub sub: ack id :{acknowledgmentNumber}");
    isPublisehd = true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _logger.Error("PushMessageToPubsub  Error : " + ex);
}
return isPublisehd;
```

}

When we try the above code, we are getting permission denied error. Please help me on this

Thank you.

Comment: Does the service account have pubsub publisher permission?